# how to update attributes in self model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

how to update self model in rails?

```
class BillSubTotal < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.total
    self.update_attributes(:total => 150)
  end
end
```

i want update value in model BillSubTotal from self model?

Comment: `self.methods` can be accessed even without instantiating objects. How would you expect `update_attributes` to work on `static` calls ?

Comment: in my model BillSubTotal i want update self attributes "total", how i can make it?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're wanting to do as how you'd go about this.

Rails automatically creates the getter/setter methods for database columns, so you don't have to create that functionality explicitly, and can just set the method like so:

```
class BillSubTotal < ActiveRecord::Base
  def update_total
    self.total = 150
  end
end
```

Or if you're working with an instance of the class directly:

```
bill_subtotal_instance.total = 150
```

Comment: i get error total undifined method?
i want to update attribute total in model BillSubTotal with value 150
how i can update value in field total from self.model?

Comment: i want update attributes from self model, and no from object from model BillSubTotal

Comment: What you want to update the total in a class method? e.g. BillSubTotal.total = 150?  Why?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

This is another convenient way to update attribute through model.
You have to call a method after create and with in that method you can update your required attribute. Here is the code snippet.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

    after_create :insert_default_data

    def insert_default_data
       self.update_attributes!(column_name: value)
    end
 end
```

Here, insert_default_data method will call after saving a new record in the database.
I think it will helpful for you...